# SQL AVG over subset of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

I'm having trouble with an average I'm trying to calculate in a frequently run query. This fiddle should show what I've got so far:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6afa9/4

Ideally I'd like to restrict the average calculation to just the 4 most recently submitted reports. So the expected result should be something like

```
+----+---------+
| id | runtime |
+----+---------+
|  1 |     600 |
|  2 |     660 |
+----+---------+
```

I've tried `OVER PARTITION` but couldn't seem to find something that was close to what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed a ROW_NUMBER() into CTE to get the most recent 4 runs by date finished.

```
;WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    DATEDIFF(minute, started, finished) AS runtime,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY finished DESC) AS RowNum
  FROM report
)
  SELECT
    id,
    AVG(runtime) AS AvgRuntime
  FROM cte
  WHERE RowNum <= 4
  GROUP BY id
```

Yields these results

```
| ID | AVGRUNTIME |
|----|------------|
|  1 |        600 |
|  2 |        660 |
```

Link to SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6afa9/8/0

Comment: Thanks for the edits :) SQL Fiddle was down when I posted the first answer, and once it came back up, I couldn't make the edits fast enough.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for taking a look at this. When you say sequential ids do you mean sequentially assigned or sequentially ordered in the report table? They are not sequentially ordered in the report table (I'd update the fiddle to try and show this, but it looks like their having some trouble again.) Also I don't think it should matter but I think the ORDER BY on line 5 should be by submitted not finished?

Comment: When I said that, I had the wrong assumption because SQL Fiddle was down and I couldn't see what your data really looked like. The answer as it is now doesn't care about that assumption and orders it by the finished column so it won't matter.